# Kotlin input first and last name with a twist

Tags: kotlin, input

Seems a pretty simple program, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**TASK** Write a program that reads the first name and the last name of a person, each on a separate line. Then, print the first letter of the first name with a dot and then the last name (with a single space in between): for example, Arthur Dent would be A. Dent

I've tried the following code:

```
fun main() {
    val s1 = readLine()
    val s2 = readLine()
    println(s1.first() +"." + " " + s2)
}
```

Which returns an error: `Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?`

This is pretty straightforward in Python, but been struggling to solve it in Kotlin.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [readLine docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html) it states that:

`Return the line read or null if the input stream is redirected to a file and the end of file has been reached.` (also if you fake an end file indication)

This means that both `s1` and `s2` are nullable. You would have seen this if you would have explicitly declared the type of the vals (something that beginners in kotlin should probably always do), as they would have been `String?`.

So, if we want to get the first letter (or do more or less anything), we need to use the `?` [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls) to avoid a NPE. The reason you don't get any error with `s2` is because the default invocation of `.toString` will just return a String with the value of `null`.

Now even if you do add the safe call you will still get an error, that being that you can't concatenate `null` to a `String`. And you can simply solve it by using template instead of concatenation (which is actually the prefered way in kotlin). So we will have this:

```
println("${s1?.first()}. $s2")
```

---

Some changes due to the single input requirement. If you only have one input of type `John Doe` then the above code won't work, because you are reading 2 separate lines, one of which does not exist, making the lastName null. Doing is for a single input needs a bit more work:

```
val line = readLine()?.split(" ")
        
val firstNameInitial = line?.getOrNull(0)?.first()
val lastName = line?.getOrNull(1)
        
println("$firstNameInitial. $lastName")
```

This assumes that there are no people with a space in their names (not sure if true or not),that nobody will enter a middle name, and that the first and last name are separated by a " " space.

---

As per [Joffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540818/joffrey)'s comment, we can also use the [elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) to ensure that the readLine is not null, by throwing our own exception stating that the input is not readable.

```
val line = (readLine() ?: error("Unexpected end of input, expected first and last name in format \"John Doe\"")).split(" ")
        
val firstNameInitial = line.getOrNull(0)?.first() // in case we receive an empty string
val lastName = line.getOrNull(1) //in case we only receive one name
        
println("$firstNameInitial. $lastName")
```

Comment: Hi Alex,
Thanks for explaining the whole null situation.
That being said, I tried both codes:

`println("${s1.first()}. $s2")`

This returns that error from the beginning: `only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?`

Following your suggestion I added `?` and this code:

`println("${s1?.first()}. $s2")`

returned:

`Test input:
Jane Doe
Correct output:
J. Doe

Your code output:
J. null`

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to add the thing that I said to add, the `?.` safe call ... I've edited the answer. As for the second part, you need to do Jane - enter - Doe - enter. Because you have 2 separate fields. If you want them to be in the same input line then you need to change a bit more in the code.

Comment: The input is done by an embedded code editor, so I don't have control over it. But I guess we're in the right direction. Only question remaining is why is s2 returning null? Because of the default invocation of `.toString`? If so, how do you fix that?

Comment: The 2nd one is returning null because it does not receive any value. You are giving both the first and last name on the same line, but reading 2 separate lines. I've added how to do it with a single input.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Alex, thank you for all the feedback and clarifications!

Comment: I would usually avoid using safe calls this way, and prefer handling the error earlier if a value is really expected on the input. For instance, you can use `val line = readLine() ?: error("Unexpected end of input, expected first name")`. This way, your variable is not nullable and the error only needs to be handled once.

Comment: @Joffrey That is definitely a very acceptable approach, one which I have used in multiple scenarios. It all depends on the actual full program and what you intend to do with it. In this scenario I've went with the simplest approach since I suspect that this is an assignment of sorts with clean data and no info was provided on what to do in case of failure.

Comment: @Alex.T This answer is definitely valid, and it totally depends on the full program as you said. But in most cases (including this one), I believe it's a bad practice to propagate nulls to the rest of the program, and since OP seems to be learning, I find it worth mentioning. In this specific case of an assignment, where it's probably expected that the input is always valid and no special error handling should happen, I would actually go for `!!`, and still not propagate nulls. But given the low cost of proper error handling here, `?: error()` is worth mentioning.

Comment: @Joffrey I've added the suggestion to the answer, feel free to edit it, or the explanation.